# Find documents where _id: { $in: myArray }

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have array with duplicates _id

```
[ 5ca751860ca74718306fe6c1,
  5ca751860ca74718306fe6c2,
  5ca751860ca74718306fe6c3,
  5ca751860ca74718306fe6c1,
  5ca751860ca74718306fe6c1 ]
```

I want select from collection all documents with _id in array (5 documents for this array), but mongo return me only unique documents (3 for this array).

My code: (playlist is an array)

```
AudioModel.find({ _id: { $in: playlist}})
```

How I can find all documents even if they are not unique?

Comment: Do duplicate ids match different documents ?

Comment: Duplicate ids it is to same documents. If array contains 3 same ids, need select 3 same documents

Comment: You'd better do it on app layer. It's doable with aggregation framework as a mental exercise, e.g. as a job interview question but it will be unpractical for production use.  Too slow and too complex with no added benefits.